# VBA Excel open multitude websites in the one IE window

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have managed with opening the Internet Explorer using VBA Excel.

My code looks as follows:

```
 Sub IE()
 Dim ie As object
 Dim location
 'Dim button
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 With ie
     .Visible = True
     .Navigate ("https://fulcrum/NewBuild/Record.aspx?ID=" & Range("B1").Value)
     .Navigate ("http://gcommswebmapgb/portal/")
     .Top = 5
     .Left = 5
     .Height = 1300
     .Width = 1900
     While ie.ReadyState <>4
         Do Events
     Wend
     Set location = .document.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE")
     'Set button = .document.getElementById("btnContainer").Children(0)
     'button.Click
     While ie.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
     Wend
  End With
  Set ie = Nothing   

 End Sub
```

In this event, the 2nd link is opened and 1st one completely omitted.
On top of that, I would like to open them in the same window (as a different tab).

I found some solutions here:

[Excel VBA control IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31922038/excel-vba-control-ie)

[VBA Excel input data into already opened ie window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794951/vba-excel-input-data-into-already-opened-ie-window)

where it looks that some functions are required.
Is anyone able to help?

Comment: You can use `.Navigate ("http://gcommswebmapgb/portal/", CLng(2048))` and this will open the second page in a new tab, but you did not solve anything doing that... Your following code will refer to that last site you opened. You must use a different approach for doing what you want. Look [here](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/index.php?thread/118371-opening-a-new-ie-tab-instead-of-a-new-window/), please...

Comment: So how to make them both opened at once? Shall I expand the With->End With statement once again?

Comment: If you proceed as I showed you, both of them will be open. But, since you cannot refer to one of them at a time, why to do that? You simple **cannot** in this way.

Comment: No mate. When I input the staff which you have shown me, the error shows "Expected =" and "Syntax error".

Comment: Then, try `.Navigate  "http://gcommswebmapgb/portal/", CLng(2048) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you store both URLs in a variables like below.

```
 Dim url1, url2 As String
 url1 = "https://fulcrum/NewBuild/Record.aspx?ID=" & Range("B1").Value
 url2 = "http://gcommswebmapgb/portal/"
```

Then try to pass the URL variables to **.Navigate** without round brackets like below.

```
 With ie
     .Visible = True
     .Navigate url1
     .Navigate url2, CLng(2048)
```

It will fix your syntax error and urls will be opened in 2 tabs.

Modified code:

```
 Sub ie()
 Dim ie As Object
 Dim location
 'Dim button
 Dim url1, url2 As String
 url1 = "https://fulcrum/NewBuild/Record.aspx?ID=" & Range("B1").Value
 url2 = "http://gcommswebmapgb/portal/"
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 With ie
     .Visible = True
     .Navigate url1
     .Navigate url2, CLng(2048)
    ' .Top = 5
    ' .Left = 5
    ' .Height = 1300
    ' .Width = 1900
     While ie.ReadyState <> 4
         'Do Events
     Wend
     'Set location = .document.getElementById("__VIEWSTATE")
     'Set button = .document.getElementById("btnContainer").Children(0)
     'button.Click
     While ie.ReadyState <> 4
         DoEvents
     Wend
  End With
  Set ie = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you need to check that your code properly references the correct tab to execute further code. Note that you cannot automate both pages at the same time. You need to switch the tabs using your VBA code to execute code on specific page.

Comment: Perfect! It works! However, in your code, the dimension parameters have been switched off. I set the Top & Left & Height & Width parameters in order to get full window open. It doesn't work now even if I keep it in the code.
Moreover, I would like to add another website too. Shall I put CLng(3072) or something like this?

Comment: Right. Keeping CLng(2048) is enough to open the 3rd tab, and I believe also the following one. I would like to set the tab dimensions, about which I wrote above. Anyway thank you so much for your help. Is such a milestone for my work!

Comment: just remove the ' before those parameters. I put the comment for testing purposes. It will make your dimensions work again.

Comment: That's what I did. I kept them without ' and it still comes small. I believe, maybe they are in the wrong place in the code and hence are omitted by VBA.